# How to store and read file content of json file in local storage

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I have a json file: `data.json`

```
[
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
      "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 4,
      "title": "eum et est occaecati",
      "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
    }
]
```

I want to save the file content in my local storage and then read the file content from local storage. So tried the following:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as data from "../data.json";    // MY JSON FILE

const setLocalItem = async (data) => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(data)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue);
    } catch (error) { }
};

const getLocalItem = async () => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
        console.log(jsonValue);
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
        // error reading value
        console.log(e);
    }
}

<>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={setLocalItem}>
        <Text>Save file</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={getLocalItem}>
        <Text>Get file</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</>
```

When I click `Get file` , I get `null` in my console. I don't know where I am going wrong in this. please help

Answer (score 0):

Your `setLocalItem` takes a `data` parameter, but you are calling it with no arguments. One way of solving it would be:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setLocalItem(data)}>
  <Text>Save file</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

A second option, since you have `data` defined at the top of the file is to *not* shadow the name in your `setLocalItem` function and take 0 parameters:

```
const setLocalItem = async () => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(data)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue);
    } catch (error) { }
};
```

And later keep your original:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={setLocalItem}>
  <Text>Save file</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, can you mark it as accepted?